# Altering custom post types with new plugin

Tags: wordpress

I created a bunch of custom post types originally using [CPT UI](https://wordpress.org/plugins/custom-post-type-ui/), but after realizing it wasn't supporting translations the way that I need I want to switch to [Toolset Types](https://wordpress.org/plugins/types/) to make translate the types. If I deactivate and delete CPT UI, would I lose the types I've already made before creating them in Toolset Types?

Comment: Unless the plugin deletes the posts which have been created under the post types you should be fine. You'd just have to recreate them with the exact post type name again. I'd suggest you create them using the create_post_type function and add it to your functions.php then you will not have to worry about a plugin.

Comment: Once you get a hang of registering CPT with functions, you will never need a plugin for it again - the args are very simple, and easy to manipulate. Your CPT should still be in your database.

Comment: Here is the WP Docs on creating custom post types: https://codex.wordpress.org/Post_Types